# Visual Spacing Layout

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I've noticed in some places (e.g. aws webinars) that the visuals layout (when creating multiple visuals) can be without spaces between them.nI have been unable to figure out how to do this hence each of my visuals has spacing between them. How is this possible?

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. Use the right tags to attract people who may help; your question is about CSS or web design, not about amazon quicksight.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently, the QuickSight team has released [custom themes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/themes-in-quicksight.html). You can remove gutters (the space between visuals) and/or margins (the space between the container and the visuals) by

- clicking the "Themes" paintbrush on the left, action-pane in the analysis
- creating a new theme (or editing an existing if you're already using a custom theme)
- clicking into the "Layout" options
- toggling "Margin" and/or "Gutter" and saving the theme

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps -

1. Go to "Themes" in the left pane
2. Under "Starter themes" click "..." and choose "Save as". This will open "Theme Editor".
3. Under "Main" Enter "Theme name" as you prefer.
4. Under "Layout" uncheck "Margin" and "Gutter"
5. Click "Save" at the top right.
6. Now under "My themes" you should see the custom theme you just created.
7. On the custom theme, Click "..." and choose "apply".